# checkBox on ListView android

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, android-listview, android-checkbox

I have this simpleList view and i want to make for each checkBox different listener.

on OnItemClick function i have toast message and i do not see it at all(if i remove the checkBox from layout xml i can see the toast...)

My code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView myList;
    List<Student> data;
    CustomAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.student_list);

        data = Model.getInstance().getAllStudents();
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter();
        myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"item click " + position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),StudentDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",data.get(position).id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows_student_list,null);
            }

            ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            TextView id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idTextView);
            CheckBox checkBox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            Student st = data.get(position);

            name.setText(st.name);
            id.setText(st.id);
            checkBox.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Please post your layout xml.

Comment: try `onItemSelected` instead of `onItemClick`

Comment: Here is my full code:[link](http://pastebin.com/iR3kjDQ8)
onItemSelected does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the CheckBox as **focusable="false"** in your XML layout.